# Why am i gettting segmentation fault (core dumped) in my C queue?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, queue, coredump

So i was trying to implement a Queue data structure in C but i keep getting this error: Segmentation fault(core dumped). I think its coming from my enqueue method. Can someone help me solve this...

This is my queue.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

void createQueue(LinkedList* list)
{
  list = (LinkedList*)calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
}

int isEmpty(LinkedList* list)
{
  int empty = 0;
  if(list->head == NULL)
  {
    empty = 1;
  }
  return empty;
}

void enqueue(LinkedList* list, Person p)
{
  LinkedListNode* newNode = (LinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
  newNode->data = p;
  if (isEmpty(list))
  {
    list->head = list->tail = newNode;
  } else
  {
    LinkedListNode* first = list->head;
    first->previous = newNode;
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
  }
  list->count ++;
}

Person dequeue(LinkedList* list)
{
  LinkedListNode* temp;
  temp = list->tail;
  list->tail = list->tail->previous;
  list->count --;

  return temp->data;
}

void viewQueue(LinkedList* list)
{
  LinkedListNode* current;
  current = list->head;
  while (current != NULL)
  {
    printf("Name: %s Birthdate: %s\n", current->data.name, current->data.birthdate);
    current = current->next;
  }
  printf("\nPeople: %d\n", list->count);
}
```

And this is my header file...

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST
#define LINKED_LIST

#define FALSE  0
#define TRUE !FALSE

typedef struct{
  char name[20];
  char birthdate[10];
} Person;

typedef struct LinkedListNode{
  Person data;
  struct LinkedListNode* next;
  struct LinkedListNode* previous;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct{
  LinkedListNode* head;
  LinkedListNode* tail;
  int count;
} LinkedList;

void createQueue(LinkedList* list);
int isEmpty(LinkedList* list);
void enqueue(LinkedList* list, Person p);
Person dequeue(LinkedList* list);
void viewQueue(LinkedList* list);

#endif
```

I also have this method to test my queue. When i run it i get a segmentation fault. Whats wrong with my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(void)
{
  LinkedList* list;
  createQueue(list);
  Person p1 = {"J Cole", "28/01/1985"};
  Person p2 = {"Kendrick Lamar", "19/01/1994"};
  Person p3 = {"Slim Shady", "17/10/1972"};
  Person p4 = {"Tupac Shakur", "12/09/1971"};

  enqueue(list, p1);
  enqueue(list, p2);
  enqueue(list, p3);
  enqueue(list, p4);

  viewQueue(list);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I think its coming from my enqueue method". Doesn't your debugging tell you exactly? A debugger will do exactly that in a few seconds.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings then fix those warnings.  These two warnings are especially important: 1) warning parameter 'list' set but not used [-Wunused-but set-parameter] in function `createQueue()`  2) warning 'list' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized] in function: `main()`  So the posted code does not cleanly compile (and these are serious warnings)  Note: when wanting to modify where a pointer points, from a called function, the pointer must be passed as" `createQueue(&list)` and that function must be modified too

Comment: when calling any of the 'heap' memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value,  it has type: `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when defining a `struct` always include a `tag name` because many debuggers cannot show the individual fields without using the tab name. It is good programing practice to separate the `typedef` declarations from the definition of the object being re-named via the `typedef`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  In this case, 10 and 20.  'magic' number make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the words `true` and `false` are properly defined in the `stdbool.h` header file.  Strongly suggest removing the `FALSE` and `TRUE` definitions from the header file and instead insert the statement `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: to avoid a lot of debug and other hassles, pass pointers to struct entities, not the whole struct

Comment: this line: `newNode->data = p;` will, at best copy a pointer.  What you really want is something similar to: `memcpy( newNode->data, p, sizeof(person);`

Comment: in function: `createQueue()`, after allocating room for a whole `linked list` entry, need to initialize all the fields. I.E. NULL, NULL, 0

Comment: the function: `enqueue()` is corrupting the linked list when the queue already has one or more entries.  When the linked list is empty it is creating a circular list, but the question asks about a queue, not a circular list.

Comment: the function: `dequeue()` fails to update the 'next' pointer in the (previously)  next to last entry in the circular list

Comment: the function: `viewQueue()` is looking for a NULL 'next' field, but the `enQueue()` function does not generate such a field for any of the items in the queue

Comment: the indenting of the code is correct, except for one thing.  When using a variable width font, two spaces are not wide enough to be easily visible.  Suggest using 4 spaces.

Comment: the function: `deQueue()`  should be returning a pointer to the entity, rather than trying to return the whole entity.

Comment: the arrays that contain the birthday field in `struct person` are 11 characters long (remember the NUL byte terminator) but the field is on defined to be 10 characters long, so the field will always be overrun, resulting in undefined behavior, which can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the code preforms several calls to `calloc()` and `malloc()`, but never passes those resulting heap memory pointers to `free()`.   While the OS will cleanup after sloppy code, you should never rely on such cleanup action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a value (like a pointer) to a routine, in order for the routine to *set* that value, you have to pass its *address*.  Thus, this line:

```
createQueue(list);
```

should be:

```
createQueue(&list);
```

if you'd like createQueue to *set* the value of the variable.  You also need:

```
void createQueue(LinkedList** list)
{
    *list = (LinkedList*) calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
}
```

Don't fret -- every C programmer makes this mistake at some point.  For more information, search for "Pass by value or reference" and "c pointer to pointer."

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value of the list pointer. You need to pass the reference.

```
void createQueue(LinkedList** list)
{
  *list = (LinkedList*)calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
}
```

And from the main

```
createQueue(&list);
```